# Gerar datas entre um intervalo em Firebird

Tags: firebird

Preciso fazer um select e retornar um intervalo de datas em firebird. Deveria ser a mesma lógica de `generate_series` do Postgresql.

> SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date
>   FROM generate_series( '2019-07-22'::timestamp, '2019-07-24'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) dd

Alguém sabe como?
Obs: Preciso fazê-lo em select, sem necessidade de functions ou algo assim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido usando `recursive`!

```
with recursive dt as (
  select cast('2019-07-22' as date) as dt
  from rdb$database
  union all
  select dt.dt + 1
  from dt
  where dt < cast('2019-07-24' as date)) select dt.dt from dt
```